# UnknownAttributeError using build for virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, associations, nested-attributes, virtual-attribute

I have a nested form containing virtual attributes :card_number and :card_verification.  When I try to build with these in the controller update action, I get ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError.

The models have a simple has_one relationship, where an appointment has_one order

```
#/models/appointment.rb
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order

  attr_accessible (...)
end

#/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appointment

  attr_accessible :email, (...)
  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification
end
```

I'm generating the form like this:

```
# /views/appointments/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for @appointment.order do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :email %>
    <%= builder.text_field :email %> # works fine on its own
    ...
    <%= f.label :card_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :card_number %>

    <%= f.label :card_verification %>
    <%= f.text_field :card_verification %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And building in the controller:

```
# /controllers/appointments_controller.rb
def update
  @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  @order = @appointment.build_order(params[:appointment]['order']) # This line is failing

  if @appointment.update_attributes(params[:appointment].except('order'))
    # ... Success
  else
    # ... Failure
  end
end
```

With this, I'm getting the error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: card_number, card_verification` when I try to submit for update, with params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"KowchWLNmD9YtPhWhYfrNAOsDfhb7XHW5u4kdZ4MJ4=",
 "appointment"=>{"business_name"=>"Name",
 "contact_method"=>"Phone",
 "contact_id"=>"555-123-4567",
 "order"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com",
 "first_name"=>"John",
 "last_name"=>"Doe",
 "card_number"=>"4111111111111111", # normally [FILTERED]
 "card_verification"=>"123", # normally [FILTERED]
 "card_type"=>"visa",
 "card_expires_on(1i)"=>"2015",
 "card_expires_on(2i)"=>"11",
 "card_expires_on(3i)"=>"1",
 "address_line_1"=>"123 Main St",
 "address_line_2"=>"",
 "city"=>"Anywhere",
 "state"=>"CA",
 "country"=>"USA",
 "postal_code"=>"90210"}},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

Everything works fine without the :card_number and :card_verification values included in the form.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

**Edit:**

I can get this working with:

```
@order = @appointment.build_order(params[:appointment]['order'].except('card_number', 'card_verification'))
```

but this seems a bit clunky.  Are there any other ways to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" is all about Mass Assignment Security. You can pass without_protection to ignore the mass assignment check.

```
@order = @appointment.build_order(params[:appointment]['order'], without_protection: true)
```

This link explains what is mass assignment security.
[Rails Internals: Mass Assignment Security](https://github.com/oscardelben/words-about-code/blob/master/2012/04/rails-internals-mass-assignment-security.md)

If you want to specify mass assignable attrs, use attr_accessible :one, :another for your model attributes.
If you need other non-model attributes, use attr_accessor :card_number, and then attr_accessible :card_number to declare and expose it.

I see you define card_number and card_verfication in Order model, but you use form_builder => f to define these two fields in html. Try using fields_for builder instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I would rather not get into the habit of bypassing Rails security measures if possible; I'm hoping there is a way to allow the mass assignment for the attributes I want (card_number & card_verification) rather than ignoring it for all attributes.